# Why won’t both of my html stuff work together

Tags: background

I am trying to decorate my background of my website I am building and for some reason I can put one or the other by themselves work but when I add both lines then only the top one works. How can I make both lines work together.

```
<body style=background-color:powderblue>
<body style=border-style:solid;border-color:red>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one `<body>` tag.

`<body style="background-color:powderblue;border-style:solid;border-color:red">`

Combine the styles into one, or move the styles to a css file or `<style>` block in your `<head>`

```
body {
  background-color:powderblue;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:red
}
```